# cpp Having trouble declarning global 2d arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, header, extern

Im trying to declare a global scope variable that i want to be accessible in all my other cpp files that in include my header file but am having some trouble.

So i have a Header File "AnimationManger.h":

```
extern const int NUM_ANIMS;
extern const int ANIM_FRAMES;
```

and my "AnimationManager.cpp" file containing:

```
#include "AnimationManager.h"
const int NUM_ANIMS = 8;
const int ANIM_FRAMES = 4;

int animArray[NUM_ANIMS][ANIM_FRAMES];

//other functions
```

I want to reference my *animArray* variable in other cpp files that i include AnimationManager.h.

Im new to cpp, having been programming with csharp as a hobby for quite a few years now im having a little trouble fully wrapping my head around how scope works in cpp, since the concept seems quite foreign to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the following lines to the .h file.

```
const int NUM_ANIMS = 8;
const int ANIM_FRAMES = 4;
```

and declare the array right after that as an `extern` variable.

```
extern int animArray[NUM_ANIMS][ANIM_FRAMES];
```

After that, the only thing left to do in the .cpp file is define the array.

```
#include "AnimationManager.h"

int animArray[NUM_ANIMS][ANIM_FRAMES];
```

---

> Im new to cpp, having been programming with csharp as a hobby for quite a few years now im having a little trouble fully wrapping my head around how scope works in cpp, since the concept seems quite foreign to me.

I hope you are using one or more good books to learn the language. Please visit [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and pick a good book to learn from, if you haven't done that already.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. So *extern* is suppose to be used 
*Not* to initially define a variable, but to define that the variable with the same name already exists and to reference the initial variable?